# Vb.net 2010 Connection to SQL Server 2008

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset, connection-string

I am trying to connection to MS SQL SERVER 2008 database (students), i want to make sure:

1) If connection string that i made is OK

```
Dim connectionString As New SqlConnection("server=X86ONX64; database=students; Integrated Security=True")
```

2) How can i check if dataset is producing any results?

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

'Connection String + DataAdaptor + DataSet
'Declared Outside Any Subroutines/Functions

Dim connectionString As New SqlConnection("server=X86ONX64; database=students; Integrated Security=True")
Dim dataAdaptor As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim objdataSet As New DataSet()


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    dataAdaptor.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
    dataAdaptor.SelectCommand.Connection = connectionString
    dataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from basic_info;"
    dataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    connectionString.Open()

    dataAdaptor.Fill(objdataSet, "StudentInfo")

    connectionString.Close()

    grd.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    grd.DataSource = objdataSet
    grd.DataMember = "basic_info"




    dataAdaptor = Nothing
    connectionString = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About your first question,** `If connection string that i made is OK`

If you did not get any exceptions, you've successfully made the connection to your database.

**About your second question.**

There are two things you can do.

1. Debug the wrong way. (It works though)

   `MsgBox(objdataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count);`
2. Learn and debug the correct way.

   Read these articles

   [Debugging Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290881%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
   [Visual Studio Debugging](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)
   [Debugging Basics: Breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4607yxb0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Anyway, learn how to use the debugger properly, put a break point, analyse the objdataSet object in a watch window and see if any results are present.

Comment: Thank you Ranhiru DataGridView now works by appending .Tables(0) and minus square brackets, i am reading Beginning visual basic 2010 by wrox, it means they have error in their code...

Comment: Oh sorry! It's Visual Basic. Square Brackets are for C# :)

Answer (score 1):

1) If connection string that i made is OK

Easy way to verify connection strings is to connect using the "Server Explorer" in Visual Studio.  Once you get a good connection, right-click on the connection and just grab the "Connection String" property.

2) How can i check if dataset is producing any results?

```
MsgBox(objdataSet.GetXML)
```

GetXML will return ALL the data in the dataset in XML format.

Also, don't globally declare variables if you don't need to.
Declare them closer, or not at all, like so...

```
Dim objdataSet As New Data.DataSet()

Using connectionString As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=X86ONX64; database=students; Integrated Security=True")

    With New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
        .SelectCommand = connectionString.CreateCommand
        .SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from basic_info;"
        .SelectCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text

        .Fill(objdataSet, "StudentInfo")
    End With

    MsgBox(objdataSet.GetXML)
End Using

'Now put it in your dataset...'
```

Hope this helps.